# Javascript native equivalent for jQuery event.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

I'm not sure, but as far as I see, `event.preventDefault` is coming from `jQuery`. if yes, I'm wondering is there any native equivalent in Javascript doing the same?

Comment: preventDefault is a DOM method. See the W3C specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation).

Comment: I don't think this question is the same as that.

Comment: @Barmar the topic is the same and the answer is suitable in both context so what value does it bring to have both?

Comment: @PraveenKumar if you read that question entirely you will see they are comparing `preventDefault` to `return false` ... my question seems similar to that?

Comment: @PHeiberg thanks! that's what I was looking for! could you post your comment as an answer, it would be helpful for others also! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`preventDefault` is a DOM method. See the W3C specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery wrap around native JavaScript event object.
`preventDefault` is JavaScript method. you can achieve `preventDefault` in jQuery by `return false;`.

Comment: yeah, I think that's true. but what about any equivalent natively in Javascript, when we have no `jQuery`?

Comment: @Mahdi preventDefault is related to  JavaScript not jQuery.

Comment: if you return false from a jQuery event handler it's equivalent to calling both preventDefault **and** stopPropagation. it's not the same as calling preventDEfault _only_

Comment: jQuery return false is take care of preventDefault as well as stopPropagation. preventDefault means stop default behavior of action eg clicking on link should not open the link. while stopPropagation is to stop other listener to listen this event.

Answer (score 0):

`return false` from *within a jQuery event handler* is effectively the same as calling both  `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` on the passed [jQuery.Event object.](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occuring, `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up and `return false` will do both. Note that this behaviour differs from *normal* (non-jQuery) event handlers, in which, notably, `return false` [does *not* stop the event from bubbling up](http://jsfiddle.net/APQk6/).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151